# I have a question very similar to an existing question, but different environments (Linux vs Windows). Re-ask or comment?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about forcing traffic all traffic to be routed over an encrypted connection (e.g., TLS) without using a VPN. It is [very similar to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/794857/redirect-all-web-traffic-through-tls-without-a-vpn.), with the major difference being the server: I do not have a Linux server. Instead, I have a Windows box (currently Windows 8.1, but I can install any version, including Server OS's if necessary) that will act as the proxy server.

Is my question different enough that I should post another question? If not, should comment on allquixotic's question? Something else?

Comment: You shouldn't edit another's person question.  All you do is offer a bounty or ask your own question.

Answer (score 3):

If an integral parameter of the question is different - in your case, different operating systems - it's a different question.

I ask a new question, and add a clarifying sentence down the lines of "I searched the site and found [link to question], but it deals with Linux and I need to perform this on Windows".