# Duplicate question, but different?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Inspired by [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1213563/changing-the-default-ansi-to-unicode-in-notepad)

Already read this meta question for [duplicate with different environment](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8939/i-have-a-question-very-similar-to-an-existing-question-but-different-environmen), and I can see the question should be left open because it is a Windows 8, not Windows 7.

However, what should we do with similar question that "I don't have folder x" or "I can't find setting x"?

For example, a question that already has answer "Change registry value of xblablablax to 1", but the new poster "I don't have the said key/DWORD/String/whatever in my registry"

Post it as new question? Comment in the original, answered question?

Please remember that the example non-existing registry problem is only example, because we can always create the required key/value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Post it as new question?

This is the correct action to take, as it will give your problem the visibility it needs in order to get an answer.

**You should ask a new question, referencing the old one if appropriate.**

---

#### Comment in the original, answered question?

Asking in a comment on an old answer to the old question is problematic because:

- The person who wrote the old answer may no longer be active on the site,
- The person who wrote the old answer may not know the answer to your new question,
- Adding a comment does not increase the visibility of the old question, so nobody else is likely to see it,

Comment: Actually, [comments *are* indexed by Google](https://www.google.com/#q=site:meta.superuser.com+%22document-centric%22&spf=1496208014975) — you may be thinking of [SE]’s search function, which is of very limited utility — but I’m not clear how that’s relevant to this discussion, one way or the other.

Comment: @Scott  Hmm. Thanks. Answer updated.